# jquery same class name click function

Tags: jquery, html

Whenever I click the comment link all of the divs are opening but i need that particular only to be opened.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="ck">comment</a>
    <div class="cmt">
        <input type="text" class="txt"/>
        <input type="button" value="submit"/>
    </div></div>
<div>
    <a href="#" class="ck">comment</a>
    <div class="cmt">
        <input type="text" class="txt">
            <input type="button" value="submit">
            </div></div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="ck">comment</a>
            <div class="cmt">
                <input type="text" class="txt"/>
                <input type="button" value="submit"/>
            </div></div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="ck">comment</a>
            <div class="cmt">
                <input type="text" class="txt"/>
                <input type="button" value="submit"/>
            </div></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cmt").hide();
    $(".ck").click(function(){
        $(".cmt").show();
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/48gfje0f/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and then filter for the first matching element:

```js
$(".cmt").hide();
$(".ck").click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll(".cmt:first").show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/48gfje0f/3/

Also, instead of using `show()` you could use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which will show and hide the relevant `div` when you click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` to "find" the required elements. In this case `$(this).next()`, because `.cmt` is the adjacent sibling of `.ck`. Just like:

```
$(".ck").click(function(){
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/48gfje0f/1/)

Comment: what to do if their is another element in between .ck and .cmt?

Comment: As @Andrew say in the other answer, `$(this).nextAll(".cmt:first").show();` should work.